# Vimscript: Placing the cursor at a defined position in the buffer

Tags: vimscript

I use vim as a note-taking app by editing a text file and appending notes to it.

I have written a simple function to insert a block of text as follows:

```
function! AddBlock2(...) range
    let l:hdr = strftime("_%d%b%y_%H-%M-%S")
    let l:b = repeat("-", 20)
    call append(line('$'), ['',l:b,'MEETING TIME : ' . l:hdr,'KEYWORDS : ',l:b, ''])
    execute "normal! G$o"
endfunction
```

I have mapped it so that it is easy to add a new header at the beginning of a meeting:

```
" append header to existing buffer
:nnoremap <C-b> :call AddBlock2() <CR>
:inoremap <C-b> :call AddBlock2() <CR>
```

This has the effect of inserting a block like this at the end of the file:

[image]

Currently the code puts the cursor at the end of the block of inserted text because of `execute "normal! G$o"`.

Ideally I would like to cursor to be placed in insert mode after `"KEYWORD: "` once the text has been inserted

How could I change the code to achieve this ? I have tried replacing the last line with `execute "normal! G?:a "` but it does not work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` needn't be called with `:norm`. Just use `?:` alone.

With your `:norm` calls there's no need to wrap in `:execute` since there are no variables being used.

And need to start insert with, well, `:startinsert`.

That gives...

```
function! AddBlock2(...) range
    let l:hdr = strftime("_%d%b%y_%H-%M-%S")
    let l:b = repeat("-", 20)
    call append(line('$'), ['',l:b,'MEETING TIME : ' . l:hdr,'KEYWORDS : ',l:b, ''])
    norm! G$o
    ?:
    norm! A<space>
    startinsert
endfunction
```

Replace the `<space>` after `norm! A` with an actual space.

You could alternatively place the cursor with movement commands (e.g. `2k$`) or function call(s) but this works just fine.

BTW, your Insert mode mapping won't work. You need to exit Insert mode before you can get to the command line...

```
:inoremap <c-b> <Esc>:call AddBlock2()<CR>
```

Comment: for whatever reason, this does not work for me - <C-b> now inserts ":call AddBlock2".literally in the buffer. I am using neovim so maybe that is the reason. I will try your suggestion 2k$

Comment: See my updated answer w/r/t the last `norm!` command and your insert mode mapping.

Comment: That now works perfectly ! Many thanks !

Comment: Great. You're welcome.